# Mail server installation in Cent OS 6.2

Tags: centos, email

I have a server with a dedicated IP. I didn't take any domain yet. CentOS 6.2 is installed on this server. I tried to install mail server in it and followed these links exactly.

- [The Perfect Server - CentOS 6.3 x86_64 (Apache2, Courier, ISPConfig 3)](http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-centos-6.3-x86_64-apache2-courier-ispconfig-3)
- [Postfix HOWTO - centos.org](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/postfix)

Everything is installed perfectly but my questions are:

1. How do I create mail id’s and where?
2. Where is my main mail panel?
3. How does the mail system work and how to manage it?
4. How to make mail system secure and customized?
5. How to make my IP address swap with a name e.g. mail.something.com not IP?
6. Can I use only IP to send or receive mail with this mail server?

I need to install mail server for my small group of 50 people and this may increase in time. I need the full installing guide of mail server from A to Z procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You question sounds like you want a web interface to your email system. (I assume that is what you mean by panel). Take a look at Squirrel Mail. It will run along side your courier server and allow your various users access via a web browser.

http://squirrelmail.org/